# Stop WebView rendering until the page is fully-loaded

Tags: android, user-interface, webview, rendering

I'm working on an app that is using WebView. Unfortunately, when user clicks a link, when the page is loading, the whole WebView area "blinks" until its loading is complete. There's also 1 more problem with it - I'm using a JavaScript that reverses colors of the page at the end of its loading - so until it's fully-loaded, the colors are normal, so again - blinking.

So, what I wannna do is "stop" rendering of the WebView, until the page is completely loaded - then, resume the rendering, so it won't blink. How to do that?

Note: I don't want to modify the webpage to achieve what I want. I have to modify WebView behavior.

And one more note, because it's maybe not clear: by "stop rendering" I mean "display currently rendered page continually until the new one is fully loaded" :)

Comment: Not to revive a dead thread but did you ever figure out how to do this properly? Is it possible to delay rendering of a webview url until after the onPageFinished event on the webview client?

Answer (score 0):

First make your **layout background color white** then make the **WebView invisible**.

after this use **AsyncTask** then put your webview **loading in doInBackground** and when it's finished in **onPostExecute** make your **webview visible**.

so the user will see the white layout first then the visible webview after fully loaded in postexcute

sorry if my english not good

Comment: Hm... This isn't really what I'm looking for. I wanted to stop rendering, not to render a blank field in place of WebView. By "stop rendering" I mean "displaying currently rendered page until a new one is loaded". Sorry if it wasn't clear; thanks for your answer, though :)

Comment: you could put another webview over the main webveiw and do the same trick..not a good solution but this is what i know

Comment: you could make visibility in
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
 public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
     // your code    
 } 
});

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a custom `WebView`, and override it's `invalidate()` method to do nothing until the page is fully loaded.